# How to Maximize, Minimize, Restore WinUI window from code

Tags: c#, winui-3

I'm creating a demo app using WinUI 3 prerelease 0.5 (project reunion).

I would like to maximize, minimize, and restore the window state from c# managed code.  Are there any examples available?

Comment: See following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72125453/window-doesnt-maximize-in-winui3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible using managed code at this time.  PInvoke is the only option currenlty.
I used PInvoke.User32 nuget package.

Comment: Can you give us the source that states that this basic function isn't possible? What I am really looking for is a way to set my app to fullscreen. No luck so far. :[

Comment: @LeBrown Jones - Nothing you can link to - I got the information through a side conversation with one of the PM's on the Project Reunion team.  You can follow the relevant conversation here: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4668

Comment: Nowadays this *can be done* from managed code. See my answer using the `AppWindow.Presenter` to maximize/minimize the window.

Answer (score 2):

Use `AppWindow` class from Windows App SDK

```cs
// Retrieve the window handle (HWND) of the current (XAML) WinUI 3 window.
IntPtr hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);

// Retrieve the WindowId that corresponds to hWnd.
WindowId windowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);

// Lastly, retrieve the AppWindow for the current (XAML) WinUI 3 window.
AppWindow appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
appWindow.Closing += AppWindow_Closing;
```

```cs
private void AppWindow_Closing(AppWindow sender, AppWindowClosingEventArgs args)
{
    args.Cancel = true;
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/windowing/windowing-overview

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation based on the PInvoke.User32 nuget package.

**Version using Window parameter**

```
    public void MaximizeWindow(Window window)
    {
        var windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);

        PInvoke.User32.ShowWindow(windowHandle, PInvoke.User32.WindowShowStyle.SW_MAXIMIZE);
    }
```

**Version using extension method**

This previous code can also be transformed into an extension method for the `Window` class, so I can just call `this.Maximize()` from within the `Window`:

```
public static class WindowExtensions
{
    public static void Maximize(this Window window)
    {
        var windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);

        PInvoke.User32.ShowWindow(windowHandle, PInvoke.User32.WindowShowStyle.SW_MAXIMIZE);
    }
}
```

Usage in your Window derived class:

this.Maximize();

**Minize and Restore**

The "PInvoke.User32.WindowShowStyle" definition used in the examples above contains also constants for `SW_MINIMIZE` and `SW_RESTORE`, but I did not test this.

Comment: User32.ShowWindow(hwnd, ShowWindowCommand.SW_MAXIMIZE);

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible using the `Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter` class. Your app window can be of different kinds, by default it's usually this one. Here's how you can use it from your code:

```csharp
// Assuming you have a reference to your window (currentWindow)
if (currentWindow.AppWindow.Presenter is OverlappedPresenter presenter)
{
    presenter.Restore();
    presenter.Minimize();
    presenter.Maximize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to maximize a window you may use this minimal class without including PInvoke.User32

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace JimPrototypes2.Services
{
    class PInvoke
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, WindowShowStyle nCmdShow);

        // Full enum def is at https://github.com/dotnet/pinvoke/blob/main/src/User32/User32+WindowShowStyle.cs
        public enum WindowShowStyle : uint
        {
            SW_MAXIMIZE = 3,     
        }

        public static void  MaximizeWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            ShowWindow(hWnd, WindowShowStyle.SW_MAXIMIZE);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 IntPtr hWnd = (IntPtr)WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(App.Window);
 PInvoke.MaximizeWindow(hWnd);
```