# WINUI 3.0 - Reunion 0.5 window size///

Tags: c#, winui, winui-3

I just start learning **WinUI 3.0** and can't find any information in google or books like **Learn WinUI 3.0** how to set default window size of application. I know in UWP it can be like

```cs
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(480, 800);
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
```

But actually it doesn't work in WinUI

Comment: Have you tested this method: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2564

Comment: Here is some info on how to maximize and minimize the Window: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71050224/4424024

Answer (score 12):

No need to do these interop calls on your own or use third-party packages for this.

Try this trifecta:

```cs
// Use 'this' rather than 'window' as variable if this is about the current window.
IntPtr hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
var windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
var appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
```

Then you can finally set the size with:

```cs
appWindow.Resize(new Windows.Graphics.SizeInt32 { Width = 480, Height = 800 });
```

Note that an `AppWindow` object has several other functions as well, like
`MoveAndResize`, `Show`, `Hide`, and features to modify the title bar.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at this repository [dotMorten/WinUIEx](https://github.com/dotMorten/WinUIEx).

It contains a method to set the window size and position

```
myWindow.SetWindowPositionAndSize(100, 100, 1024, 768);
```

I also found an example in the [WinUI3 Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-3-Demos/blob/420c48fe1613cb20b38000252369a0c556543eac/src/Build2020Demo/DemoBuildCs/DemoBuildCs/DemoBuildCs/App.xaml.cs#L41)
I'm adding the relevant code here for easy reference

```
private void SetWindowSize(IntPtr hwnd, int width, int height)
{
    var dpi = PInvoke.User32.GetDpiForWindow(hwnd);
    float scalingFactor = (float)dpi / 96;
    width = (int)(width * scalingFactor);
    height = (int)(height * scalingFactor);

    PInvoke.User32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, PInvoke.User32.SpecialWindowHandles.HWND_TOP,
                                0, 0, width, height,
                                PInvoke.User32.SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOMOVE);
}
```

Comment: To get hWnd: var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(m_window);

Comment: The second example also requires the PInvoke.User32 nuget package to be installed.

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment on answers yet but to add to Jonas' answer, you can put his answer in the class constructor (where this.InitializeComponent() is) of your main window code-behind or in the OnLaunched method of App.cs. I'm sure that seems obvious to a lot of people but to those coming from other languages/platforms it might not be. Example:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        
        IntPtr hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this); // m_window in App.cs
        WindowId windowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
        AppWindow appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);

        var size = new Windows.Graphics.SizeInt32();
        size.Width = 480;
        size.Height = 800;

        appWindow.Resize(size);
    // or like Jonas said:
    // appWindow.Resize(new Windows.Graphics.SizeInt32 { Width = 480, Height = 800 });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the most recent versions of WinUI, Window now has the `AppWindow` property.  This means the solution offered by @Jonas can be simplified:

```
   protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
   {
        MainWindow = new Window();
        MainWindow.AppWindow.Resize(new Windows.Graphics.SizeInt32 { Width = 480, Height = 800 });

        ...
   

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. You will need to add the nuget package PInvoke.User32.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    m_window = new MainWindow();
    m_window.Activate();

    //Get the Window's HWND
    var windowNative = m_window.As<IWindowNative>();
    m_windowHandle = windowNative.WindowHandle;

    m_window.Activate();

    SetWindowBounds(0,0,100,100);
}

private Window m_window;
private IntPtr m_windowHandle;
public IntPtr WindowHandle { get { return m_windowHandle; } }

[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("EECDBF0E-BAE9-4CB6-A68E-9598E1CB57BB")]
internal interface IWindowNative
{
    IntPtr WindowHandle { get; }
}


public void SetWindowBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    var dpi = PInvoke.User32.GetDpiForWindow(m_windowHandle);
    float scalingFactor = (float)dpi / 96;
    width = (int)(width * scalingFactor);
    height = (int)(height * scalingFactor);

    PInvoke.User32.SetWindowPos(m_windowHandle, PInvoke.User32.SpecialWindowHandles.HWND_TOP,
                                x, y, width, height,
                                PInvoke.User32.SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOMOVE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of [WinUI3 1.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel#version-14), `this.AppWindow.Resize(new(800, 400));` in the Window's constructor, after `InitizeComponent()`, has the same effect

with the "new" being a `Windows.Graphics.SizeInt32` object, Width**x**Height